No Wi-Fi Settings After Reboot on HP-d15 Laptop Running Ubuntu
I recently installed Ubuntu on my HP-d15 laptop, and everything was working perfectly until I shut it down a couple of hours ago. When I turned it back on, I noticed that the Wi-Fi settings were completely missing, and I can no longer connect to any Wi-Fi networks.
I have an airplane mode key on my keyboard, but pressing it doesn’t seem to change anything. I’ve already tried several terminal commands and basic troubleshooting steps, but nothing has resolved the issue.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
